# Python console_script entry point runs as Python2

Tags: python, linux

I have a package that sets up an entry point `console_script` and i want the `console_script` to run the python function/script as Python3

My package uses the `urllib.request` module (Python3).

Running the command (the `console_script`) gives a python error about `request` not being a module, thats why i'm thinking it executes my script as Python2..

---

**__main__.py**

```
import urllib.request
...

...
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_path, progress)
...
```

**error**

```
ImportError: No module named request
```

---

```
python --version
Python 2.7.13

python3 --version
Python 3.5.4rc1
```

Comment: share the error message. also check `python --version` and share that.

Comment: Check if you are doing `from urllib import request` and then using `request` module.

Comment: Will post my code in a couple minutes

Comment: @VikashSingh Done...

Comment: It crashes on the `import` line, not the line where i used the `urlretrieve` ..

Answer (score 2):

`console_script` scripts are executed using whatever version of Python was used to install their package, e.g., if you installed the package with `pip`, `pip2`, `python2 -m pip`, or the like, the script will always run under Python 2.  Either uninstall the package and re-install it with Python 3 or else use something like [six](http://pythonhosted.com/six) to ensure your script will work under both versions.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by uninstalling my package from all pip's (`pip`, `pip2`, `pip3`)
and then reinstalling my package using `sudo pip3` (notice the `sudo` part ..)